# Only clear the form fields when post data submit successfully in php and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to clear the form files only if I get successful data submit call back. To do that I use PHP which `echo "Your application submit successfully!";`  and pass this message string back to Jquery which displays it into `#response`. But somehow it is not working. the if condition in jquery cannot detect the
`Your application submit successfully!` is there something that I am missing?

PHP:

```
if($query)
{

     echo "Your application submit successfully!";

}
else
{

 echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
        <b><i class='fas fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Something Went Wrong. Your data is not inserted!</b>
        </div>";
}
```

Jquery:

```
success: function (data) {

 if(data != null && data == "Your application submit successfully!"){ 
     $('#enroll_form').trigger("reset"); //reset fields
         } else { 

              $('#response').fadeIn().html(data); //this line render html+text 
                        setTimeout(function(){  
                             $('#response').fadeOut("slow");  
                        }, 7000);


         }
```

Comment: Please see the dupe. Do not rely on error message string tests when you decide to change the text. Instead send a JSON response with a defined content of data.success or data.error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking for the whole text I would check for just a chunk of that sentence:

```
if (data != null && data.toLowerCase().includes("successfully") {
```

Otherwise you are more likely to make a typo and your code is more likely to fail.

And consider showing always the response, not in the else:

```
if (data != null && data.toLowerCase().includes("successfully") {
    $('#enroll_form').trigger("reset");
}
$('#response').fadeIn().html(data); 
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#response').fadeOut("slow");  
}, 6000);
```

Comment: Perfect answer. yeh I guess the problem was the white spaces between those chunks:p